# x-init only being called once

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

In my code, if I call two x-init's only the first one thats in the root DOM Element will br ran.

How do I use muliple x-init's?
do i just use on in the handler?

https://jsfiddle.net/qfcdo5bL/1/

```
<form action="/some/url" method="POST" x-data="someHandler()" x-init="console.log('this will print in console')">
        ... 
        <div  x-init="console.log('this will NOT print in console')">
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </form>
    <script>
    function jpeHandler() {
        return {
          data: {'foo':'bar'},
          init(){
            return console.log('this will NOT print in console');
          },
          }
     }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x-init` only works on the element that has `x-data` so you won't be able to run something on init in a child element unless you make it a separate Alpine component (by adding `x-data` to it)